# how to show excel like background graph for asp.net graph?

Tags: asp.net, data-visualization

I'm able to generate a 3d stacked cylinder graph in asp.net 4.0 web application.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int pointIndex = 0; pointIndex < 5; pointIndex++)
        {
            Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(45, 95), 0));
            Chart1.Series["Series2"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(5, 75), 0));
            Chart1.Series["Series3"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(5, 95), 0));
            Chart1.Series["Series4"].Points.AddY(Math.Round((double)random.Next(35, 95), 0));
        }

        Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
        Chart1.Series["Series4"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;

        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Color.Red;
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].Color = Color.Black;
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].Color = Color.Blue;
        Chart1.Series["Series4"].Color = Color.Pink;

        Chart1.Series["Series1"]["PointWidth"] = (0.6).ToString();
        Chart1.Series["Series2"]["PointWidth"] = (0.6).ToString();
        Chart1.Series["Series3"]["PointWidth"] = (0.6).ToString();
        Chart1.Series["Series4"]["PointWidth"] = (0.6).ToString();

        Chart1.Series["Series1"].LegendText = " ";
        Chart1.Series["Series2"].LegendText = " ";
        Chart1.Series["Series3"].LegendText = " ";
        Chart1.Series["Series4"].LegendText = " ";
    }


<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="500px" Height="500px">
<Series>
    <asp:Series Name="Series1" CustomProperties="DrawingStyle=Cylinder">
    </asp:Series>
    <asp:Series Name="Series2" CustomProperties="DrawingStyle=Cylinder">
    </asp:Series>
    <asp:Series Name="Series3" CustomProperties="DrawingStyle=Cylinder">
    </asp:Series>
    <asp:Series Name="Series4" CustomProperties="DrawingStyle=Cylinder">
    </asp:Series>
</Series>
<ChartAreas>
    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
        <Area3DStyle Enable3D="True"/>
    </asp:ChartArea>
</ChartAreas>
```

Above code display the graph like below,
[image]

All fine and as expected so far, but I need to get rid of **GRAY** background and need to display background grid lines like below that generated by Excel,

[image]

Second question, can we rotate the each bar in graph, currently it's display the current 3d settings?

Answer (score 0):

Make below changes in your code:

```
<Area3DStyle Enable3D="False" />
```

It should work now.

Comment: <Area3DStyle Enable3D="False" />

Comment: Instead of posting the code in the comments you should include it in the answer itself.